# How to get total count of orders placed on spesific date using Raw query

Tags: sql, sqlite, ormlite

I have ORDER Table in which I am saving Orders date wise.
Now I want total number of orders placed on specific date

How to do that
Pls Help...

Comment: Consider providing schema and sample data. sqlfiddle will help you.

Comment: What've you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE DATE_COL = 'YOUR_DATE'
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue.